# Changing colour of Woocommerce rating stars and text

Tags: css, woocommerce

I would like to change the colour of the rating stars, the text next to them ("5 customer reviews") and the stars in each review further down the page.

I have tried several codes but none of them work.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks,

Jerome

https://www.wildeones.com/shop/45-minute-psychic-video-reading-with-andie-hudson/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @vladislav you can look at what styles are causing the color to be set.

In the case of the stars the color is set by:

`.woocommerce .star-rating span:before`

You can look through the theme to find this CSS and change it to set the color. Or if thats not possible you can try and apply more specific css to override the color.

If you get stuck providing more specific styles you could use `!important`. e.g.

```
.woocommerce .star-rating span:before {
  color: <put your new color here> !important;
}
```

The text on the "5 star reviews" is targeted as `a` to set the color, so you can override that just for the rating by using the class name on that link. e.g.

```
.woocommerce-review-link {
  color: <put your new color here>;
}
```

I found all this information by using the dev tools ["inspect element tool"](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/inspect-element-in-chrome) of the browser. If you want to learn more about applying CSS based on specificity the MDN docs are useful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thanks very much. Is this correct?: .woocommerce .star-rating span:before {
  color: #FFC300 !important;
}                                                       This comment box won't let me add a screenshot. Is the code to go under Theme Customizer / Additional CSS?

Comment: Yes you can add it under the additional CSS. And yes your code looks ok. You'll have to try it out and see though! Do try to learn the inspect element tool and how CSS specificity works though so you can troubleshoot further problems.

Comment: Brilliant, it is working now. I didn't realise I had to exit the customiser and refresh the page in order to see the changes. I have a long way to go. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. If you feel like the answer answered your question I'd love and appreciate it you accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Hi Pure Function. I'm having a new issue: the button, hover and text colours no longer correspond to the code. They come up as a paler shade. Do I need to start a new ticket? Thanks.

Comment: Yep @Jerome for a new issue its best to start a new question.